# Linq for getting words in sentences

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a List of *words* and a List of *sentences*.
I want to know which **words** can be found in which **sentences**.

Here is my code:

```
List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
List<string> words = new List<string>();

sentences.Add("Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae, nostra Galli appellantur.");
sentences.Add("Alea iacta est.");
sentences.Add("Libenter homines id, quod volunt, credunt.");

words.Add("est");
words.Add("homines");

List<string> myResults = sentences
  .Where(sentence => words
     .Any(word => sentence.Contains(word)))
  .ToList();
```

What i need is a list of Tuples. With the sentence and the word, that was found in the sentence.

Comment: What's exactly the problem?

Comment: *"i need is a list of Tuples"* - just write `new { Sentence = ..., Words = ...}` or what is the problem? Btw, `Hashset` would be more appropriate for words.

Comment: I need a List of Tuples instead of the List<string>.
So how can i use the new {...} with the word and the sentence in the querry?

Comment: I think this is a very good question, but you have to give us some information so that we can help you for example what is the definition of a sentence for you ?

Comment: "I need a list of Tuples" is not a question. The idea is that you try something and have you have a specific problem, you come and ask.

Comment: Are you trying to build an inverted index? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#Inverted_indices Example: https://codefying.com/2015/12/31/inverted-index-in-c/

Comment: Hi, You question is not cristal clear may you [edit] a little [mcve] with exemple into your question just few sentence and words and the expected result

Comment: @sonyfuchs , don't forget the expected result please. It look like a details but it will clarify if there is a grouping on Sentence or word or none.

Comment: How about using `foreach`?

Comment: You can iterate over the sentences and check which words match in the current sentence then construct your list of tuples

Comment: are partial matches acceptable? e.g. "this is my greatest triumph" sentence will match the word "great" with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way,

```
var result = from sentence in sentences
             from word in words
             where sentence.Contains(word)
             select Tuple.Create(sentence, word);
```

Comment: thank you, i tried it in method syntax, but it's easyer in querry syntax

Comment: Counter example: `"in"` word should be found in the *1st* sentence only; your code returns *3d* sentence as well.

Comment: hom*in*es you are right, I will try to address your issue in a separate answer in case this is relevant to the OP.

Comment: I ended up upvoting your answer

Comment: var results = sentences.SelectMany(sentence => words.Where(word => sentence.Contains(word)).Select(word => (sentence, word)));

Answer (score 7):

First, we have to define *what is word*. Let it be *any combination of letters and apostrophes*.

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\p{L}']+");
```

Second, we should think over on what shall we do with *case*. Let's implement *case insensitive* routine:

```
  HashSet<string> wordsToFind = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "est",
    "homines"
  };
```

Then we can use `Regex` to match words in the sentences, and *Linq* to query the sentences:

**Code:**

```
  var actualWords = sentences
    .Select((text, index) => new {
      text = text,
      index = index,
      words = regex
        .Matches(text)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(match => match.Value)
        .ToArray()
    })
    .SelectMany(item => item.words
       .Where(word => wordsToFind.Contains(word))
       .Select(word => Tuple.Create(word, item.index + 1)));

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, actualWords);

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  (est, 1)         // est appears in the 1st sentence
  (est, 2)         // est appears in the 2nd sentence as well
  (homines, 3)     // homines appears in the 3d sentence
```

If you want `Tuple<string, string>` for *word*, *sentence*, just change `Tuple.Create(word, item.index + 1)` for `Tuple.Create(word, item.text)` in the last `Select`

Answer (score 4):

Do you just mean this:

```
IEnumerable<(string, string)> query =
    from sentence in sentences
    from word in words
    where sentence.Contains(word)
    select (sentence, word);
```

That gives:

[image: query]

Comment: thank you, i tried it in method syntax, but it's easyer in querry syntax

Comment: Counter example: `"in"` word should be found in the *1st* sentence only; your code returns *3d* senctence as well. `Contains` generate false positive for `"homines"`